# Multi Series MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am a newbie in MSChart and the code below works for a multi-series column.
But I know there should be a shorter way to show Multi-Series without
resorting to creating two Data Tables or much better with very few codes like
using DataBindTable or DataBindCrossTable.

Is there a shorter way of doing what I am doing below? What I am trying to do by the way is to show how many students enrolled in a given School Year.

```
String sql, sql2;

sql = @"SELECT Major, SchoolYear,  COUNT(*) as TotalStudents 
                FROM StudentList 
                WHERE Major='AFT' 
                GROUP BY Major, Schoolyear";

sql2 = @"SELECT Major, SchoolYear,  COUNT(*) as TotalStudents 
                FROM StudentList 
                WHERE Major='AFT' 
                GROUP BY Major, Schoolyear";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dta = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
        dta.Fill(dst);
        dt = dst.Tables[0];

        chart1.Width = 900;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "School Year";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Enrollment";

        chart1.Series[0].Name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "SchoolYear";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "TotalStudents";
        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dt.CreateDataReader(),"SchoolYear", dt.CreateDataReader(), "TotalStudents");


        dta = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, con);
        dst = new DataSet();
        dta.Fill(dst);
        dt = dst.Tables[0];
        chart1.Series.Add(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "SchoolYear";
        chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "TotalStudents";
        chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(dt.CreateDataReader(), "SchoolYear", dt.CreateDataReader(), "TotalStudents");
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try below?

```
String sql, sql2;

sql = @"SELECT Major, SchoolYear,  COUNT(*) as TotalStudents 
                FROM StudentList 
                WHERE Major='AFT' 
                GROUP BY Major, Schoolyear";


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dta = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
        dta.Fill(dst);
        dt = dst.Tables[0];

        chart1.DataSource = dt;

        chart1.Width = 900;
        chart1.ChartAreas["abc"].AxisX.Title = "School Year";
        chart1.ChartAreas["abc"].AxisY.Title = "Enrollment";

        chart1.Series["xyz"].Name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        chart1.Series["xyz"].XValueMember = "SchoolYear";
        chart1.Series["xyz"].YValueMembers = "TotalStudents";


        chart1.DataBind();
```

HTML:

```
            <asp:Chart ID="chart1" runat="server" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ImageLocation="ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)">
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="abc">
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Thank you @user1828411. Man you dig this one ha? ;-) Anyway I will try it out later. By the way I am not using ASP but I am using WinForms in other words this is a desktop application. Thank you again and GOD bless.

Comment: this does not solve my problem but it gives me hint on finally solving this one and hence the upvote for you ;-) Thank you and GOD bless.